# UnnecessaryStubbingException when mocking LoggerFactory for isDebugEnabled

Tags: java, logging, junit, mockito, loggerfactory

I am trying to improve my branch coverage and mocking Logger to check both cases of "isDebugEnabled".

Below is my test case:

```
@Test
    public void testLogger() {
        try (MockedStatic<LoggerFactory> 
                loggerFactoryMockedStatic = mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class)) {
            Logger logger = mock(Logger.class);
            loggerFactoryMockedStatic.when(() -> LoggerFactory.getLogger(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(logger);
            
            when(logger.isDebugEnabled()).thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE);
            Response res = endpoint.check();
        }
        
    }
```

but it is resulting in "UnnecessaryStubbingException" when i am setting the debug enabled.

Any idea how can I get it done ?

Comment: Your endpoint class is probably loaded before the mock could be set up (new to static mocks, but a static logger is initialized when the class is loaded. That happens on the first reference of the class (e.g. `new Something` or `Something.staticMethod()`). `endpoint` is already assigned before the method is entered).

Answer (score 0):

Enable the debug logging accordingly for testing configuration.

You could consider to run all the tests with all available logging levels for warning-/info-/trace-enabled, etc separately, perhaps as part of extended testing. Then combine all the log-results and coverage for reporting.